# How to unzip multiple ziped files and rename automatically if needed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, zip

I have a bunch of Ziped files in a folder, and i would like to unzip all with:

```
unzip ZIP/*.zip
```

But automatically rename folders or files with the same name, example:

In `ZIP_folder_1.zip` and `ZIP_folder_2.zip` i have one folder called `my_name`, if i unzip all with the command above, the command line will ask if i want rename it, so, if i have 3k folders with the same name, i will go crazy. Is it possible to do automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} -d {}.contents/;
```

This should work and extract every zip file in a folder with the name of the zip file.

Comment: What if i have multiple files inside??

Comment: The name of the directory is going to collide with the actual zipfile.  Maybe something like `find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} -d {}.contents/;`